# Image update in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue updating images for my posts in CodeIgniter.

I have no probleme creating posts with images, but when I try to update a post, post changed info are updated bu not the image.
I have tried several posibilities from different tutorials without success

Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

### controller

```
public function create(){   
    
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('users/login');
    }
    $data['title'] = 'Create Post';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else 
    {
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
        
        $post_image =  $this->upload_image();           
        
        $data = array(          
            'title'         => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug'          => $slug,
            'body'          => $this->input->post('body'),
            'post_image'    => $post_image
        );
        
        //$this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
        $this->post_model->create_post($data);

        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created successfully!');
        redirect('posts');
    }
}

public function edit($slug)
{       
    $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
    
    // Check if logged user has created this post 
    if($this->session->userdata('user_id') != $this->post_model->get_posts($slug)['user_id'])
    {
        redirect('posts');
    }
    $data['categories'] = $this->category_model->get_categories();

    if(empty($data['post']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Edit Post';

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/edit', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function update()
{
    // Check login
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect('users/login');
    }
    $id=$this->input->post("id");
    
    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
    
    if( $_FILES['userfile']['name']!="" )
    {
        $post_image = $this->upload_image();
    }
    else
    {
        $post_image=$this->input->post('old');
    }
    
    $data = array(          
        'title'      => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug'       => $slug,
        'body'       => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image
    );
    
    //$this->post_model->update_post($post_image);
    $this->post_model->update_post($data,$id);

    // Set message
    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated successfully!');
    redirect('posts');
}

public function upload_image()
{       
    // Upload Image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '2000';
    $config['max_height'] = '2000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
    {
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';            
    } 
    else 
    {
        $upload_data=$this->upload->data();
        $post_image=$upload_data['file_name'];
    }
    return $post_image;
}
```

### **model**:

```
public function create_post($data)
{
   return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
}   
public function update_post($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);            
    return $this->db->update('posts', $data);
}
```

**view (edit view)**:

```
<?php echo form_open('posts/update'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden"  id="old"  name="old"  value="<?php echo $post['post_image']   ?>">
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Add Title" value="<?php echo $post['title']; ?>">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Body</label>
        <textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add Body"><?php echo $post['body']; ?></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Change Image</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
    </div>      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: when you try to update the post, did you upload the image again or just leave it as it is? OR in the update form `value="<?php echo $post['post_image']` this is the image name?

Comment: Do this `exit($this->upload->display_errors());` instead of what you currently have for upload errors and see if it says anything.

Comment: Hi Alex, thamks for replying. "post_image" is the image name field in my database. I've tried exit($this->upload->display_errors()); but no error message. When I try to upload the image, normaly if an image is selected for upload it should take it otherwise it keeps the old one

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how anything is uploading as `do_upload()` doesn't declare the the name of the file field. In this case I suppose it is `userfile` e.g. `do_upload('userfile')`.

Consider doing something with you file uploads error variable as this should have uncovered your error rather quickly.

EDIT:

My bad, apparently `do_upload()` default file name parameter for upload is `userfile`. My guess now as to why it isn't working is that your "update" form, doesn't use `form_open_multipart`!

---

Please note: you can also move your redirect function back to login to the controllers constructor. This will eliminate some lines of duplicate code.

Also if you are looking for an *easy* way to get the errors of the upload function you can do the following:

```
private function upload_image()
{       
    // Upload Image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '2000';
    $config['max_height'] = '2000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
    {
        throw new Exception($this->upload->display_errors());
        //$errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //$post_image = 'noimage.jpg';            
    } 
    else 
    {
        $upload_data=$this->upload->data();
        $post_image=$upload_data['file_name'];
    }
    return $post_image;
}
```

Usage:

```
try {
    $this->upload_image();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    show_error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The update works fine but the image is not updated so I have no error even when i use do_upload('userfile'). I recieve the message ('Your post has been updated successfully!')

Comment: I've tried somme debogging and the probleme is that in the update function, 'userfile ' is undefined. I've just changed "if( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] != '' ) TO if( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] == '' ). But I'm trying to figurout how to fix it.

Comment: I think the probleme is in upload_image() function. I'm using the same function for create and update, it works for creating but it doesn't for updating (it can't read $_FILES['userfile']['name'] to update). I don't know why?

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you would expect to not see "Your post has been updated successfully!" as you do nothing if the upload function generates errors. `if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
    {
        exit($this->upload->display_errors());
    }` try this to see whats happening

Comment: And after looking at your view you need to change `form_open` to `form_open_multipart`.

Comment: Fixed! The problem was very simple (I believe I was stupid) because I forgot to use form_open_multipart instead of form_open. Thanks too too much.

Comment: There was no error when updating because I've set the default value in 'post_image' field in my database to 'noimage.jpg' witch is (the image file) already in the upload folder. so when I create a post and no image was uploaded the post will have 'noimage.jpg' as post image. I assum it was not a good idea for debugging.

Comment: I suspect we both figured it out at the samish time haha